# Prometheus Alert Not Firing

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I have an alert rule
-alert: HighCPUUsage
expr: sum(rate(system_cpu_usage{container="container-name",namespace="namespace"}[1m]))/sum(kube_pod_container_resource_limits{container="container-name",namespace="namespace",resource="cpu"})*100>0.01 (0.01 is only to test if the alert would fire)

Prometheus UI shows that alert is firing but I am not receiving any email.
I receive alerts for my other rules but for this one, I don't know why I am not receiving any

Comment: Check the receiver config.
make sure it is well-formed and correct.

Comment: If Prometheus UI shows that it is firing, change the "Prometheus Alert Not Firing" title to something like "Alertmanager is not sending alert e-mail". You need also to add the Alertmanager config.

Comment: first step u must be check your integration config then if u sure about config check alerts and restart to fire .

Comment: It would be helpful if you share your configuration. we could better understand the situation and suggest a solution.